# Android set layout_weight, but skip the last padding?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to create 3 equal layout items in Android.

This is easily achievable with `layout_weight` attributes, but how can I skip the last margin part?

[image]

Layout sample:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="0.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="48.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="40.0dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:includeFontPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="0.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="48.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="40.0dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:includeFontPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="0.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="48.0dip" 
        android:layout_height="40.0dip" />

    <TextView 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:maxLines="1" 
        android:includeFontPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Please note that `ImageView` and `TextView` should be centered to each other even in the last column.**

Please also note: ConstraintLayout is not usable (Business requirement).

Comment: Where is root layout ?

Comment: use contraintlayout instead

Comment: In the last `LinearLayout`, change the `layout_gravity` from `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to `android:layout_gravity="end"`. Or, shift to `ConstrainyLayout` and use constraints.

Comment: First suggestion does not work, second is not possible due to business reqs. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0.0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="48.0dip"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:includeFontPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0.0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="48.0dip"
        android:layout_height="40.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:includeFontPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0.0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="48.0dip"
            android:layout_height="40.0dip" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:includeFontPadding="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's close to perfect, but I needed to change the weights to 3-3-2 and now seems good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Or use `ConstraintLayout` for better control.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
            
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="48.0dip"
                        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
            
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="test" />
            
                </LinearLayout>
            
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
            
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="48.0dip"
                        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
            
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="test" />
            
                </LinearLayout>
            
            
            
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
            
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="48.0dip"
                        android:layout_height="40.0dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="end" />
            
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="test" />
            
                </LinearLayout>
            
                <View
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"/>
            
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not working. Please see my screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/gaRz477

Comment: You need to rephrase your question then , what is it exactly that you want to achieve . Is it ok with ConstraintLayout if so , i shall try it

Comment: ConstraintLayout is not usable due to a business requirement. It's in the question since my last update. Do you think it still need more rephrasing? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer and this is as far as i could go , altering the weights. Otherwise you need a custom view extending the `LinearLayout`

Comment: If I remove the last `View` the unwanted right margin goes away, but in this case the label is not centered below the ImageView. If last `View` stays, it creates the right margin which I want to remove as per the question.

Comment: You'd want to add some margin or prefer using calculated presets programatically.